# encoding special characters in python2

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding, character-encoding

I have a piece of code that works well in Python3:

```
def encode_test(filepath, char_to_int):
    with open(filepath, "r", encoding= "latin-1") as f:
        dat = [line.rstrip() for line in f]
        string_to_int = [[char_to_int[char] if char != 'ó' else char_to_int['ò'] for char in line] for line in dat]
```

However, when I try to do this in Python2.7, I first got the error

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xc3' in file languageIdentification.py on line 30, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

Then I realize that I may need to add #coding=utf-8 at the top of code. However, after doing this, I encountered another error:

```
UnicodeWarning: Unicode unequal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal
string_to_int = [[char_to_int[char] if char != 'ó' else char_to_int['ò'] for char in line] for line in dat]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "languageIdentification.py", line 190, in <module>
test_string = encode_test(sys.argv[3], char_to_int)
File "languageIdentification.py", line 32, in encode_test
string_to_int = [[char_to_int[char] if char != 'ó' else 
char_to_int['ò'] for char in line] for line in dat]
KeyError: u'\xf3'
```

So could anyone tell me what could I do to solve this problem in Python2.7?

Thank you!

Comment: Python 3 `str` objects are actually the equilalent to Python 2 `unicode` objects, and Python 2 `str` objects are equivalent to Python 3 `bytes`. Just convert *everything* to unicode objects at the source and work with those.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Actually I cannot make changes on the source file. Is there anyway that I can do directly in the program?

Comment: What? You mean in your text file? You have to change your code, you can't expect to be able to re-use python 3 code in Python 2 when the nature of the `str` type fundamentally changed

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Sorry for the typo. I mean I cannot make changes on the source text file. So can you suggest any method to solve this through encoding and decoding in the program?

Comment: Yes. At the source where you read in a string, convert to a `unicode` object. Then *only work with unicode objects*.

Comment: You may use Unicode literals: `u”Unicode string in python 2.7”`

Comment: @EugeneLisitsky Sorry I wasn't sure how to do this. Could you please use my code for illustration. Like should I do u'line.rstrip()' ?

Comment: Replace all strings typed in code to Unicode. Like:  'ó' with u'ó'

Comment: @EugeneLisitsky I tried this and replace 'ó' with u'ó' , 'ò' with u'ò', but I still got a keyerror u'\xe9' because 'ó' is not a key in the dictionary char_to_int. So I guess this conversion still does not work. Do you know how should i fix this? Thank you

Comment: @Parker, you shouldn't use u'...' for dict keys

Comment: @Parker how do you form `char_to_int`? If it contains only Latin-1 symbols you cannot take ‘ò’ from there.

Comment: @Parker, if the problem is solved, could you please accept one of the answers?

Comment: @MaximTitarenko Sure, I thought I have done that. Sorry for this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you try to **compare unicode-string and byte-string**:

```
char != 'ó'
```

Where `char` is a unicode and `'ó'` is a byte-string (or just str).

When Python 2 faces with such a comparison, it tries to convert (or decode):

```
byte-string -> unicode
```

The conversion is provided with a default encoding which is ASCII in Python 2.
Since byte-value of `'ó'` is higher than 127, it leads to the error (UnicodeWarning).

By the way, for literal which byte-value is in ASCII-range, comparison 
will be successful.
 
Examples:

```
print u'ó' == 'ó' # UnicodeWarning: ...
print u'z' == 'z' # True
```

So, in comparison you need to convert your byte-string to unicode manually.
For example, you can do that with built-in `unicode()` function:

```
u = unicode('ó', 'utf-8') # note, that you can specify encoding
```

Or just with `'u'`-literal:

```
u = u'ó'
```

But be aware: with this option the convertion will be implemented through the encoding you specified at the top of the source file.
So, your actual source encoding and the encoding declared at the top should match.

As I see from the `SyntaxError` message: in your source `'ó'` starts with `'\xc3'`-byte.
Therefore it should be '`\xc3\xb3'` which is UTF-8:

```
print '\xc3\xb3'.decode('utf-8') # ó
```

So, `# coding: utf-8` + `char != u'ó'` should solve your problem.

**UPD.**

As I see from the `UnicodeWarning` message - there is the 2nd trouble: `KeyError`

This error occurs in the statement:

```
char_to_int[char]
```

because `u'\xf3'` (which actually is `u'ó'`) is not a valid key.

This unicode comes from decoding your file (with `latin-1`).
And I suppose, that there are no unicode keys in your dict `char_to_int` at all.

So, try to encode such a key back to its byte-value with:

```
char_to_int[char.encode('latin-1')]
```

**Summarizing**, try to change the last string of provided code to:

```
string_to_int = [[char_to_int[char.encode('latin-1')] if char != u'ó' else char_to_int['ò'] for char in line] for line in dat]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert character to its integer value you may use `ord` function, it works well for Unicode too.

```
line = u’some Unicode line with ò and ó’
string_to_int = [ord(char) if char!=u‘ó’ else ord(u’ò’) for char in line]
```